# Hartogs' theorem for real functions

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

**Context**: Hartogs' theorem says that if a complex function $f:\mathbb{C}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is separately analytic in the two complex variables, then the function is continuous, and analytic. However, this fails when applied to real function. The counterexample given in Wikipedia is $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, given by 
$$
f(x,y) = \frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}.
$$
$f$ is not continuous along the lines $x=\pm y$.

**Question**: This raises two questions:

1. Clearly, being separately analytic in x (i.e. keeping y constant, vary x) and separately analytic in y is not enough to ensure continuity, let alone analyticity of $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. However, is it true that if $f$ is separately analytic along *all* directions in the $\mathbb{R}^2$ plane, then $f$ is analytic?
2. Is the converse true? Specifically, if $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is analytic, then is it analytic along all directions in the $\mathbb{R}^2$ plane?

**Note**: By analytic along a certain direction, I mean the following: Consider the line $y=mx$ in the plane. Along this line, $f(x,y) = \tilde{f}(x)$, since x completely parametrizes the line. Then, being analytic along this line, in the sense that I'm using it, would mean that $\tilde{f}(x)$ is analytic in x.

I apologize if this is a very simple question. I'm new to analysis, and would appreciate it if you could provide references where this has already been proven or disproven.

Comment: what does analytic mean for $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$? Is it that, for each $(x_0,y_0) \in \mathbb{R}^2$, there exist $(a_{m,n})_{m,n \ge 0}$ such that $f(x,y) = \sum_{m,n \ge 0} a_{m,n}(x-x_0)^m(y-y_0)^n$ in a neighborhood of $(x_0,y_0)$?

Comment: if so, converse should be clear: $\sum_{m,n \ge 0} a_{m,n} (x-x_0)^m(y-y_0)^n = \sum_{m,n \ge 0} a_{m,n}(x-x_0)^m(mx-mx_0+mx_0-y_0)^n = \sum_{m,n \ge 0} (x-x_0)^m \sum_{j=0}^n {n \choose j}(mx-mx_0)^j(mx_0-y_0)^{n-j}$ and keep going

Comment: Thanks mathworker21, that makes sense. Yes, analytic in the sense of convergent power series in x and y as you said. Right, so the converse seems true by your arguments. How about the other way round?

Comment: I think I've heard that that is false at some point in my life. But I don't know a proof or reference right now. Maybe I'll come back to it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first answer I gave (see below) is correct, but perhaps is a bit gimicky. Here I give a more substantial solution as an answer to the question @Fimpellizieri asked.

Claim: There exists $f:\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R$ that is real analytic on every line in $\mathbb R^2$ but fails to be analytic as a function of two variables in every neighborhood of $(0,0).$

Proof: Define

$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases} \frac{x^2y}{x^2+y^2},&(x,y)\ne (0,0)\\0,& f(0,0)=0.\end{cases}$$

On the $x$ and $y$ axes $f\equiv 0.$ On lines $y=mx,m\ne 0,$ $f(x,mx)=[m/(1+m^2)]x.$ On horizontal lines $y=c\ne 0,$ we have

$$f(x,c)=\frac{cx^2}{x^2+c^2},$$

which is analytic as a function of $x$ on $\mathbb R.$ On vertical lines $x=c,c\ne 0,$

$$f(c,y)=\frac{c^2y}{c^2+y^2},$$

which is analytic as a function of $y$ on $\mathbb R.$ All other lines can be written $y=mx +b$ with both $m,b\ne 0.$ Here we get

$$f(x,mx+b)=\frac{x^2(mx+b)}{x^2+(mx+b)^2}.$$

Because the denominator never vanishes, we have analyticity on all of these lines as well. Thus the first part of the claim is proved.

Now suppose $f$ can be written as a power series of two variables near $(0,0).$ Because $0=f(0,0)=\partial f/\partial x (0,0) = \partial f/\partial y (0,0),$ this power series has the form $ax^2+bxy+cy^2$ plus terms of higher order. Looking at the line $(x,x)$ then gives $x/2 = O(x^2)$ as $x\to 0.$ This is a contradiction, and proves the claim.

---

**Previous answer**: Define

$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}x^2 & \text {if } x=y\\0&\text {if } x\ne y\end{cases}$$

Then $f$ is analytic on each line through the origin, but as a function of two variables, it is discontinuous at each point of the line $y=x$ except for the point $(0,0).$

Comment: This is a good example for directions, and I upvoted it. I wonder if there is an example for when the function is still separately analytic for each variable (which is not the case here: if you fix some nonzero value for $x$ or for $y$, then $f(x,y)$ is not analytic).

Comment: @Fimpellizieri So you would like a counterexample that is analytic on each horizontal /vertical line and on every line through the origin?

Comment: If that exists, yes.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri I believe I've answered your question. See my edited answer.

Comment: Very nice! Thank you for the comprehensive answer.